# Help to run a .sh script

Tags: unix, shellexecute

I've my .sh script as

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Usage: sync.sh DIRECTORY_LOCATION"
    exit 1
fi

DIRECTORY_LOCATION=$1

DEV_INSTANCE_IP=<some ip>

# Update data
scp -pR ${DEV_INSTANCE_IP}:${DIRECTORY_LOCATION}/* ${DIRECTORY_LOCATION}/
```

How do I run this script??

I tried `sh sync.sh <path to directory>` but it echos the line `Usage: sync.sh DIRECTORY_LOCATION`. Does that mean it's being run??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's running, `-z` flag means

```
-z STRING      True if string is empty.
```

If either first argument or second is empty --> exit.

one way of getting more information is to change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` this will tell bash to print every line that is executed including the value of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The $1 in this script means it's expecting another entry for the DIRECTORY_LOCATION. So, you would need:

bash sync.sh *directoryname*

Also, instead of using sh *scriptname.sh*, it's better to do "chmod +x scriptname.sh".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ahem, the script requires a second (bogus = never used) argument in  the condition `|| [ -z "$2" ]` if you delete that part, it should work as the authors meant it to be used, whatever this may be ;-)
At least it should work the way you called it, namely `sh sync.sh <path to directory>.` 
And no, if you only provided this one argument in your version, it preinted the usage and exited undone.
You can also just provide a second argument (as long as you do not mix-up with the two, i.e. providing the directory as the second arg would not help ...